# Php counting with $i++

Tags: php, loops

I have this in a loop:

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    echo '<div id="'.$i.'">' . 'Anchor' . '</div>';
    echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . 'Link-A ' . '</a>';
    echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . 'Link-B ' . '</a>';
    $i++;
?>
```

This works fine if there is only one object. What do i have to do if i want the "$i" to count so that i get:

```
<div id="1">Anchor</div>
<a href="#1">Link-A </a>
<a href="#1">Link-B </a>

. . .

<div id="2">Anchor</div>
<a href="#2">Link-A </a>
<a href="#2">Link-B </a>

. . .

<div id="3">Anchor</div>
<a href="#3">Link-A </a>
<a href="#3">Link-B </a>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < count($collection); $i++){
        echo '<div id="'.$i.'">' . 'Anchor' . '</div>';
        echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . 'Link-A ' . '</a>';
        echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . 'Link-B ' . '</a>';
    }
?>
```

It is a basic for loop.

Comment: What is `$collection` over here

Comment: @Uchiha he doesn't show any variable containing a collection of items. so I had to make one up.

Comment: But this'll lead to undefined variable for OP as it seems OP is not familiar with simple basic loops too

Comment: With this i only get "#0" in the loop. `elseif (get_row_layout() == 'accordion'):
         // Rows of content
   for($accordion = 0; $accordion < count($accordion); $accordion++) {

    if( have_rows('accordion_zeile') ):
     
        echo '<div id="accordion'.$accordion.'">
           <div>';

       while ( have_rows('accordion_zeile') ) : the_row();
        echo '<a data-parent="#accordion'.$accordion.'">';
        echo 'Link </a>';

       endwhile;
       endif;
   }      

      echo '</div></div>';`

Comment: @orestiss This depends if you're going trough an array or something else. if you're going trough an array you'll surely want to start at 0, and $collection would be a predefined collection, as stated in a comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Just change `$i` value to print that many objects.

```
<?php
    $i = 2;

    for( $j=1; $j <= $i ; $j++ )
    {
        echo '<div id="'.$j.'">' . 'Anchor' . '</div>';
        echo '<a href="#'.$j.'">' . 'Link-A ' . '</a>';
        echo '<a href="#'.$j.'">' . 'Link-B ' . '</a>';

    }
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just produce `<div id="2">` every iteration?

Comment: No, it will have incrementing id's.. Try this code once

Comment: thx, this helped me to understand that i first have to count "$i".

Answer (score 0):

if you have your strings stored into an array you could do something like:

```
<?php
 $myarray = array( "Anchor1"=> array("linkA1","linkB1"),
                    "Anchor2"=>array("linkA2","linkB2"));

    $i=1;
    foreach($myarray as $k => $v ){
     echo '<div id="'.$i.'">' . $k . '</div>';
     echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . $v[0] . '</a>';
     echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . $v[1] . '</a>';
     $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is `$myarray` over here

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
 echo '<div id="'.$i.'">' . 'Anchor' . '</div>';
 echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . 'Link-A ' . '</a>';
 echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . 'Link-B ' . '</a>';
 echo '<br/><br/>';
 echo '. . . <br/><br/>';
}
```

It will produce the output

```
<div id="1">Anchor</div>
<a href="#1">Link-A </a>
<a href="#1">Link-B </a>

. . .

<div id="2">Anchor</div>
<a href="#2">Link-A </a>
<a href="#2">Link-B </a>

. . .

<div id="3">Anchor</div>
<a href="#3">Link-A </a>
<a href="#3">Link-B </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php code you are not creating a loop. You are just creating a variable and incrementing it later. You should read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp).

Here is basic example of `for loop`

```
<?php
  for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
     echo "Variable i is equal to:".$i."!";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<50)
{
echo '<div id="'.$i.'">' . 'Anchor' . '</div>';
echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . 'Link-A ' . '</a>';
echo '<a href="#'.$i.'">' . 'Link-B ' . '</a>';
$i=$i+1;
}
?>
```

This code would work perfectly! Just make the condition $i`<`n!! Where 'n' can be replaced with your number of loops!